# Bind to same function in Python

Tags: python, wxpython, publish-subscribe

I need to use two events to send a message from child frame to main frame and close the child frame (by using pubsub). One of the events is the click event of a "Cancel" button on the child frame and the other one is the close event of the child frame. So I use a common "OnClose" function for both of them. Here is my related code:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id=cancel.GetId())`

`self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose )`

```
def OnClose(self, event):
    self.Close()
    Pubsub().sendMessage(("show.mainframe"),"")`
```

Every time I close my child frame, it actually doesnt close and when I try to reopen the child frame from the main frame, a new child frame is generated on top of the previous one. 
Actually I solved this problem by using the code inside the destructor function (**del**). But I am curious why in the first method it doesnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *But I encounter a problem* - what problem would that be?

Comment: Do you want us to guess which problem it is? *Where do I go wrong?* Based on the currently given information, it could be anything.

Comment: You should post which gui toolkit you're using.  Tkinter?  GTK?  Qt?

Comment: Should we guess what toolkit you are using? How about precise questions?

Comment: Well, it's tagged "wxpython" and some of his stuff is pre-pended with "wx"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your calls in your OnClose method. Put the pubsub call first and the Close call last. Or just use Destroy() at the end instead of Close().